# Autohotkey: Open windows explorer and wait till active window before proceeding

Tags: autohotkey

Really struggling with this.

I need to simply open a windows explorer window at a specified domain, wait until it is active then proceed. This is what I have so far:

```
#::
{
  WinGet, old_active, ID, A
  Run, explore C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Test FDA

  loop{
    WinGet, new_active, ID, A
    if(ahk_id %new_active% != ahk_id %old_active%)
    {
      WinMaximize, A
      break
    }
  }
  return
}
```

EDIT SOLVED ?>>>

DIDNT KNOW WINDOW SPY EXISTED CAME WITH IT :(((

Long time wasted, this simply works.

```
[::

{

Run explore C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Test FDA

WinWaitActive Test FDA

WinMaximize A

return

}
```

Comment: Just a note, You might want to use WinWait then WinActivate instead. What I found is that if you have something open that demands the foreground, like cmd.exe then the window will never be active by itself.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?:

"
F12::
WINDOWEXPLORER:
    WinWaitActive, Windows Explorer,, 0.01
        if ErrorLevel
        {
            Goto WINDOWEXPLORER
        }
        else
        {
;       SoundBeep 4500, 30
        Return
        }
"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `WinWaitActive` function. From the documentation:

> Waits until the specified window is active

Put it after the line with `Run...`:

```
WinWaitActive, WinTitle
```

You will need to replace `WinTitle` with the title of the window that comes up after the `Run` command. There are other options available, such as duration to wait, titles to exclude, etc.

See the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) for more details.

Comment: I have looked at other ways but it is for work.

Regarding WinTitle Autohotkey says that it uses illegal keys for autohotkey when referring to a windows explorer window :( that is why I am using the ID.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Also I can't find/think of a way to obtain the WinTitle without it being active anyway.

Comment: `WinTitle` doesn't need to be exact -- it will be matched using [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm). You could specify just the start, or a string contained in WinTitle, for example.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, if it works I will post :)

Thanks again